# Unable to understand and parse the JSON URL response

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a json url and I am trying to extract data from the response. below is my code

```
url = urllib2.urlopen("https://i1.adis.ws/s/foo/M0011126_001_SET.js?func=app.mjiProduct.handleJSON&protocol=https")
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
print(soup.items)
newDictionary=json.loads(str(soup))
```

Below is the response.content

> app.mjiProduct.handleJSON({"name":"M0011126_001_SET","items":[{"type":"img","src":"https://i1.adis.ws/i/foo/M0011126_001_MAIN","width":3200,"height":4800,"format":"TIFF","opaque":"true"},{"type":"img","src":"https://i1.adis.ws/i/foo/M0011126_001_ALT1","width":3200,"height":4800,"format":"TIFF","opaque":"true"},{"type":"img","src":"https://i1.adis.ws/i/foo/M0011126_001_ALT2","width":3200,"height":4800,"format":"TIFF","opaque":"true"}]});

I am new to JSON and unable to understand the response. In addition, I need to parse the response in json or in some form to extract image sources. But the above code gives me below error.

> No JSON object could be decoded

Can Anyone please guide me ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

first of all your url isn't working it returns `app.mjiProduct.handleJSON({"status":"error","errorMsg":"Failed to get set"});`

the second thing is that you don't have to pass the content to Beautifulsoup, you could pass it directly to json like I did in my code bellow without the Beautifulsoup object.

I used `httpbin` to test but this should work in your url. I used python3 tho

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
url = urlopen("http://httpbin.org/get")
content = url.read()
newDictionary=json.loads(content)
print(newDictionary)
```

output: `{'args': {}, 'headers': {'Accept-Encoding': 'identity', 'Connection': 'close', 'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'User-Agent': 'Python-urllib/3.6'}, 'origin': '', 'url': 'http://httpbin.org/get'}`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that worked for me.

```
json_data=url.read()
purify_data = json_data.split('handleJSON(')[1].split(');')[0]
loaded_json = json.dumps(json_data)
print(loaded_json['items'][0]['src'])
```

actually, I figured out that json_data was of type string and I was unable to decode because of the format of that string, that was

> app.mjiProduct.handleJSON(REQUIRED JSON)

So, first I filtered my string and then loaded it with json and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The response doesn't contain valid JSON. It looks like a executable code (probably JavaScript). But the part `{"name":"M0011126_001_SET","items":[...]}` is valid JSON. So if you know for sure that response has always this format you can strip the function call like this:

```
content = url.read()[26:-2] # Cut first 26 characters and last two
newDictionary=json.loads(str(content))
```

I don't know much the Beautiful Soup but what I find it's a library for processing HTML files while your response is not HTML so I think you shouldn't use it for it.